# How to derive the Lorentz force via a Lagrangian formulation?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

Consider a free particle in a curved spacetime $M$ with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, then the action that can be used to describe this particle is

$$S[x(t)] = \int \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}^\nu} dt = \int \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}^\nu} \frac{\delta^{(3)}(x-x(t))}{\sqrt{-g}}dV,$$

where $dV = \sqrt{-g} d^4 x$ is the invariant spacetime volume element.

Usually, when one wants to couple a theory to Electromagnetism, the replacement $\nabla_\alpha \longmapsto\nabla_\alpha - i q A_\alpha$ gives you a theory coupled to an external electromagnetic field, where $q$ is the charge of the system you are coupling. However, I do not see a $natural$ way of coupling the action above with electromagnetism. Although the standard way to couple a charged particle with the electromagnetic field would involve adding a term

$$q\dot{x}^\mu A_\mu$$

to the Lagrangian gives the correct Lorentz force and coupling, this seems rather Ad-Hoc, and I can't think of any good justification(on mathrmatical terms) for adding this term to the Lagrangian.

Trying to write $\dot{x}^\mu$ in terms of partial derivatives with respect to the time coordinate does not yield any meaningful result either...

Is there any way to obtain the coupling of a charged particle with electromagnetism via the Lagrangian above that does not involve adding ad-hoc terms like $q\,\dot{x}^\mu A_\mu$ and that can be justified without a handwavy argument such as "this is the current associated to a chaged particle?".

That is, is there a "first principle" way to obtain the coupling of a charged particle with electromagnetism?

Comment: The [generalization on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Lagrangian_mechanics#General_relativistic_test_particle_in_an_electromagnetic_field) appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the EOM for a charged relativistic particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78648/finding-the-eom-for-a-charged-relativistic-particle)

Comment: I know about this way of inserting the coupling, but this looks so much Ad-Hoc. Why doesn't the standard way of coupling work? Also, by adding the term $\dot{x}^\mu A_\mu$ to the Lagrangian, you are effectively adding a current density of the form
$$j^\mu = \dot{x}^\mu \frac{\delta^{(3)}(x-x(t))}{\sqrt{-g}}.$$
Is this even conserved?

Comment: Thanks! I just added a clarification in the end

Comment: Maybe consider a free particle action in 5 dimension like in Kaluza-Klein theory?

Comment: @Rick why is your dirac delta 3 dimensional instead of 4 dimensional? Regarding your current, it does seem to be conserved at first glance, did you try taking an explicit covariant derivative?